# How to enable SSL for the built-in WSGI server from Python?

Tags: python, security, ssl, https, wsgi

I run a WSGI application from within my Python file, using the `make_server` command.

(I don't know if this is a good practice or whether it is more common to setup Apache or nginx for this purpose.)

**I want to make this little server secure by adding SSL support. Where do I start?**

Is the built-in WSGI server from Python considered safe? I want the connection to be really secure. I only recently came across WSGI and I thought it was very easy to use, especially from within Python. The app is only used as a proxy so has little functionality, but I do want it to be as secure as possible.

Comment: http://pydoc.net/Python/urllib3/1.1/dummyserver.server/ found this example but it does not use make_server.

Comment: http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@p@r@proxython-HEAD@libs@eventlet-0.9.15@tests@wsgi_test.py/379/eventlet.wrap_ssl here is some unit tests that uses ->> sock = eventlet.wrap_ssl(eventlet.listen(('localhost', 0)), 
                                        certfile=certificate_file, 
                                        keyfile=private_key_file,
                                        server_side=True)

Answer (score 1):

Basically `WSGI` is just an interface for communication between a web-server software (e.i. `nginx` or `httpd`) and your python script/app which contains some code to process requests (usually either `application` callable or `applications` list of callables).

You need to enable SSL on the web-server layer. But if you don't want to involve external software you may follow @Demz's advice and try using `eventlet.wrap_ssl`. Please find more relevant information [here](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/wsgi.html#ssl).